# How to compute the average of n rows and paste the answer to next n rows of pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, moving-average

I have a weekly sales dataframe

```
Sales           weekNum 
83                    1 
139                   2 
207                   3 
278                   4 
274                   5 
291                   6 
319                   7 
305                   8
```

I want to compute the average of first 4 weeks and paste it in the index of week 5 to 8

And I want my output dataset to look like below

```
Sales   weekNum   4-PreviousWeekAverage
83            1 
139           2 
207           3 
278           4 
274           5          176.75
291           6          176.75
319           7          176.75
305           8          176.75
```

Similarly I also want to compute the 8 week average and paste it in the index of 5 to 8

I tried

```
for i in [4, 8]:
    newColumnName1 = '%s-PreviousWeekAverage' % i
    df[newColumnName1] = np.nan


    for ix in df.index:
        if ix - i >= 0:

            df.loc[ix, newColumnName1] = np.mean(sampledf.loc[ix-i:ix-1,'Sales'])
```

However it returns me the moving average like below

```
Sales   weekNum 4-PreviousWeekAverage
83           1  
139          2  
207          3  
278          4  
274          5            176.75
291          6            224.5
319          7            262.5
305          8            290.5
```

I am having an issue in looping , no able to figure out the correct script. Hence will appreciate the help.

Comment: What exactly is the issue with the second output? Why does your expected output all have the same numbers?

Comment: @coldspeed, The issue is I don't want a moving average. I want only the average of 1st four weeks

Comment: But your question title said "how to compute moving average". Would you please consider updating your title to something that more meaningfully reflects what you actually want? One huge problem with questions in the pandas tag is that the titles are badly written, so people looking for solutions to these questions cannot find it because of the way the question is written.

Comment: @coldspeed I have changed my question. Apologies it was unintentional and I didnt mean to confuse. Thanks

Comment: Definitely better, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`groupby` on weekNum and `transform` by `mean`.

```
df.groupby((df.weekNum - 1) // 4).Sales.transform('mean').shift(4)

0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4    176.75
5    176.75
6    176.75
7    176.75
Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC

```
df.at[4:,'4-PreviousWeekAverage']=df.Sales.iloc[:4].mean()
df
Out[344]: 
   Sales  weekNum  4-PreviousWeekAverage
0     83        1                    NaN
1    139        2                    NaN
2    207        3                    NaN
3    278        4                    NaN
4    274        5                 176.75
5    291        6                 176.75
6    319        7                 176.75
7    305        8                 176.75
```

Comment: Wen,Thanks for the answer, but actually my dataset extends way beyond 8 rows , so the open indexing won't work well for my problem.